# Linq. Missing table

Tags: linq

I have 3 tables: table1 with columns(ProductId, name, etc), table2 (DocumentId, name, etc), table3 (ProductId, documentId). When I create a .edmx model I have only table1 and table2 in my model, I can't see table3. How can I get the Documents for Products if the table3 is missing?

Comment: Through the [navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382841.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that when you create the model, you have both in Products, a property called Documents, and in Documents, a property called Products.

To see Documents in a Product, then call:

```
var documents = DbContext.Documents.Include("Products").ToList();
```

and the same for products

```
var products = DbContext.Products.Include("Documents").ToList();
```

and then you will have Products as a collection for each Document and Documents as a collection for each Product

This happends to every Many to Many table in EF.